# I'm upgraded my project to Razor view engine, but VS2010 still auto-generates WebForms

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have upgraded to MVC3 and Razor, everything works fine. However, in my `return View(model);` the "View" is red and VS2010 will helpfully suggest I generate a view. When I do, it generates a aspx/WebForms view.  There's no other aspx files in the project, and if I run the project, the Razor view engine works fine. There's obviously a setting somewhere that tells VS2010 which to default to, I can't find it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not explicit answer but rather a list of actions that you could try..

- In the csproj file of your project make sure that the `<ProjectGuidType>` are set to `<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>`
- Try changing the `ProjectGuid` to some other Guid ([last post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1643601.aspx/2/10?Upgrade%20an%20MVC3%20project%20with%20aspx%20viewengine%20to%20Razor%20viewengine#426102)). You will need to update the sln file or simply recreate the solution.
- Not sure what method you used to upgrade, but have a look at the [MVC 3 Upgrade Tool](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/marcinon/archive/2011/01/13/mvc-3-project-upgrade-tool.aspx) from [CodePlex](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/59008)

Answer (score 1):

If you can create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project and add a Razor view as expected then the project where you are seeing this behavior is missing the ASP.NET MVC 3 project type guid, which you can find in a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project's .csproj file. If you can't do this than you should try reinstalling the ASP.NET MVC 3 Tools Update.